# Magnific Popup: Close floats to the right

Tags: magnific-popup

I have a problem using the Magnific Popup on my site here: http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/stage/

Try to click on the usericons on the top right corner. Somehow the X is positioned to the right and not just above the popup. I've yet to find the solution that fixes this. Anyone who knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please fix your HTML first, otherwise I can’t be bothered to even start to look for reasons for a specific behaviour: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/stage/

Comment: A W3 test is not very useful. It make even simple html an error. I have yet to find a major bug that should cause this.

Answer (score 0):

The div with `id="loginbox"` should be relatively positioned:

```
 position: relative;
```

The `X` button is an absolute position element and it is positioned relative to its first parent element `(loginbox)` that must have a position other than static.

Comment: If I do that, the X just goes down on the right side. I must have some code messing with the plugin, but I really dont know why :l